# Unique dummy object of generic type in C# (to mark deleted slots in array)

Tags: c#, generics

I have an array of generic type inside my class.

I am practicing implementing open addressing HashTable (generic version) with different probing - and **I want to mark slots of deleted elements**, so I can tweak optimisation later (swap items during search and insert into "deleted" slots).

Usually people use **some kind of dummy object** for this purposes - they assign it to the slot of deleted item and than compare array elements to it during other operations.

But I am not sure if I can do it with generic type in C# - I want to use the HashTable with any Key types -  both reference and value. So I don't want to Key to implement any kind of interface.

I saw it used in Java like this:

```
K DUMMY_DELETED = (K) (new Object());
if(keys[i] == DUMMY_DELETED)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to work this out for C# without obliging Key to implement some interface? Or should I use a wrapper for the key-value inside my class?

Comment: _" addressing HashTable (generic version)"_ called `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

Comment: If you add on your (hopefully generic class) a generic type constraint like `where T: new()`, you could create a `private static readonly T Empty = new T();` and use that.

Comment: A wrapper like that for value types already exists; it's called `Nullable` -- and for reference types, wrapping the comparer to treat `null` specially is also doable. Of course this won't do if you want to be able to store `null` values explicitly. The only fully generic solution that wouldn't require wrapping types is a separate list of deleted slots, which has its own performance challenges.

Comment: Yes, it should be a generic class and you could add a constructor: `MyGenericClass(Func<T> getDeletedItem)`. Then you are flexible, it does not need to be `new T()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: that's just kicking the can down the road by forcing the client to come up with a way to cough up an object that doesn't compare equal to any other, meaning it is also required to play nice with any comparer being passed. That said, if you do go down that road, there seems to be no reason to not just pass a `T` instead of a `Func<T>` -- we need only the single dummy object, there is no particular benefit to creating multiple, or initializing it lazily. In general `Func<T>` is of course a good substitute for a constructor call.

Comment: Thanks everyone for suggestions! I am not a C# pro by any means, butI have a feeling that wrapping up key-value pair into some kind of private Entry class with "Deleted" flag will be most straightforward solution to preserve fully-generic approach.

Comment: Generics in Java and C# are implemented differently, and you can't do what you want this way in C#. Why not just use `null` or `default(T)` (which would be `null` for reference types)?

Comment: @DStanley The point is to mark array cell in a unique way  so "empty" and "deleted" cells will be different.  For the reference types there will be no difference between "empty" and "deleted". And also if I will use defalt(T)  I will have to prohibit default values of value types for the end user (like 0 key value for int).

Comment: @neuromouse Fair enough. However generics do not work that way in C#. You could just define it as a `HashTable<object>` and just cast non-deleted items, but C# does not use the same type-erasure that Java does that lets you technically use any type. Or define an interface or wrapper class that has an `IsDeleted` property.

Answer (score 0):

Generics are implemented differently in Java and C#, so you can't use objects other than the generic type like you can in Java. Some options:

- Use `Dictionary<TKey, object>` and do the cast yourself for non-deleted items
- Constrain `TValue` to an interface that has an `IsDeleted` property
- Define a wrapper class that contains the object, has a pass-through `Value` property, and has an `IsDeleted` property. (Similar to `Nullable<T>`)
- Inherit from `Dictionary<TKey, KValue>` and keep track of deleted "slots" in a separate property.